# Scala testing: What's the status and relationship of SUnit, ScalaTest, ScalaCheck, Specs and ParTest?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, scala, specs, scalatest

Scala provides a choice of different testing frameworks, but I wonder if there are differences in the maturity and stability they have and which distinct features they provide.

Is there a specific one which should fit for all kinds of development?

Can the different frameworks inter-operate with each other or with test runners targeted for other languages?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- SUnit [no longer exists](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/24995).
- ScalaTest and Specs are mature, maintained, and receiving improvements (Specs2 is recently out, by the way). Choice between them is a matter of taste.
- ScalaCheck doesn't have a particularly good runner, but both ScalaTest and Specs have special support for ScalaCheck integration. It is considered an important tool.
- ParTest is used just for the compiler, as it tests stuff like "does this compile?" and "does this *not* compile?", error and warning messages, etc. It is not targeted at application development, and shouldn't be used for that.

Comment: partest might, however, be useful for *library* / DSL development. See [this discussion on scala-user](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/gdfOmtXn1v4/discussion).

Answer (score 9):

ScalaTest and Specs have a very similar syntax and feature list and they are both adopted by the community. They both allow unit and acceptance tests.

ScalaCheck has a radically different philosophy. Tests generate random instances and check taht some properties hold. Properties and generators can be defined and composed in a nice functional idiom. ScalaTest and Specs allow you to write ScalaCheck properties inside tests.

SUnit was removed before a started programming in Scala so I have no idea how it worked. I never heard of ParTest before your question.